# Error while trying to implements two ArrayStacks -Java

Tags: java, arrays, stack

So I am working on a program that will read a math equation in the form of a string EG: 1 + 2 * 3

I need to have two different stacks, one for the numbers others for the operands. Push the numbers onto the number stack and push the operators onto the character stack then process the equation when certain conditions are met. We are using ArrayStacks that I have imported into the enviroment. However I keep getting an error while trying to compile the stacks.

Here is what I have:

```
public static String test = new String("2 * 3 + 6 ");
public static ArrayStack<Double> numbers = new ArrayStack<Double>[20];
public static ArrayStack<Character> operands = new ArrayStack<Character>[20];
```

It keeps giving me this error (Ran with -Xlint):

```
infixNotation.java:7: error: generic array creation
public static ArrayStack<Double> numbers = new ArrayStack<Double>[20];
                                           ^
infixNotation.java:8: error: generic array creation
    public static ArrayStack<Character> operands = new ArrayStack<Character>[20];
                                                   ^
/home/tyler/CSC223/bookFiles/ch03/stacks/ArrayStack.java:22: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    stack = (T[]) new Object[DEFCAP];
                  ^
  required: T[]
  found:    Object[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class ArrayStack
/home/tyler/CSC223/bookFiles/ch03/stacks/ArrayStack.java:27: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    stack = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
                  ^
  required: T[]
  found:    Object[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class ArrayStack
/home/tyler/CSC223/bookFiles/ch03/stacks/StackOverflowException.java:3: warning: [serial] serializable class StackOverflowException has no definition of serialVersionUID
public class StackOverflowException extends RuntimeException
       ^
2 errors
3 warnings
```

Comment: I think it should be public static ArrayStack<Double> numbers = new ArrayStack<Double>(20); instead of the square brackets. You need to pass the size of the array to the constructor of the ArrayStack, and not use the array index notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public static ArrayStack<Double> numbers = new ArrayStack<Double>[20];`

The [20] indicates you are making an array of twenty ArrayStacks. But this is clearly nonsense, as you didn't even declare the field as an array (among other things).

You probably meant to call its constructor with 20, so `(20)`

`public static ArrayStack<Double> numbers = new ArrayStack<Double>(20);`

Comment: That did seem to solve the errors, however it keeps reporting:

Note: /home/tyler/CSC223/bookFiles/ch03/stacks/ArrayStack.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.


Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


Which is the file that I am importing

Comment: That probably means the `ArrayStack` was implemented by a halfwit. You'll have to live with it.

Comment: @JefferyTylerStewart Sounds like there's something wrong with your generics. What lines generate the warnings?

Comment: So that note is not going to affect running the code? Essentially it is not an error?

Comment: Did you try recompling with `-Xlint` as suggested to see what the details are?

Comment: This code is being ultra screwy. Sometimes when I try to compile it gives me that note, while other times it does not. It seems to be working fine atm... Thanks

Comment: I suggest that it only gives you the note if code that uses ArrayStack.java is recompiled.